# What did they call illegitimate children in Old English days?

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology, kinship-terms, archaicisms, old-english

I know that the word *bastard* in this sense appeard only in 13<sup>th</sup> century. So what was the normal term before that?

Comment: Another way of putting it, maybe: what was [William the Bastard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_the_Conqueror) called before he was called William the Bastard?

Comment: To be clear, the 13th century after the Old English days.

Comment: @Jonathan: ?? Is your comment to your own answer? The question is about OE, your answer -looks- like OE, but your comment here (not with your answer) makes it sound like you're saying it is ME.

Comment: Wow, I misread the question (thought it said “after”, not “before”)! My bad. That's what happens when you've got an axe to grind, I suppose.

Comment: @Dori perhaps as "William the Bastard", since while it was only English since the 13th C, it was French since about his time.

Comment: @Dori The Norman French term was batard, but I've never come across the OE version of that name.

Answer (score 9):

Actually, in the Old English days, the word for “bastard” was *cifesboren*.

Comment: oh, that's rather concrete. thnx!

Comment: @Juls My pleasure!

Comment: A literal translation of the term is _harlot-born_ or _concubine-born_, _cifes_ being the Anglo-Saxon for “concubine, harlot” (the connection _boren_ “born” speaks for itself).

Comment: *mistress* rather than concubine/harlot might be a better translation of *cifes* these days.

Answer (score 8):

There are many references in genealogies and histories of *natural sons* and *natural daughters* of nobles and royalty during the Middle Ages -- people like [Meiler Fitzhenry](http://what-when-how.com/medieval-ireland/fitzhenry-meiler-medieval-ireland/) (son of Henry I of England), [William Longsword](http://books.google.com/books?id=4qFY1jpF2JAC&pg=PA589&lpg=PA589&dq=william%20longsword%20%22natural%20son%22&source=bl&ots=Xhy1NDM3a-&sig=YxbfBUR_QntX3Ty4a1cObsCM2-I&hl=en&ei=Tg6jTeBs5onRAf_ZiZQF&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=10&ved=0CEkQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=william%20longsword%20%22natural%20son%22&f=false) (son of Henry II of England), [Hamelin Plantagenet](http://familytreemaker.genealogy.com/users/w/a/r/W-R-Warren/WEBSITE-0001/UHP-0612.html) (son of Geoffrey of Anjou), and [Joan of Wales](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joan,_Lady_of_Wales) (daughter of King John of England). These references date from the 12th century, and the same terms appear to have been in use as late as the 18th century.

Answer (score 2):

In Medieval Latin, dating from the 11th Century, the equivalent was *bastardus*.

Comment: Oh, I've found myself 'uterine' - born of the same mother but not necessarily of the same father...

Answer (score 1):

[Robert Burns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Burns) (1759-1796) wrote to his [love-begotten daughter](http://www.poemhunter.com/poem/a-poets-s-welcome-to-his-love-begotten-daughter/).